# Tomcat: @Overriden log filter mixing outputs with its non-overridden variant

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, tomcat7, servlet-filters

`FullRequestDumperFilter` was created as an Java class extension of `RequestDumperFilter` [- part of Tomcat](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/filters/RequestDumperFilter.java).

`FullRequestDumperFilter` is my custom Tomcat log filter to log full HTTP Requests and Responses including bodies, while `RequestDumperFilter` logs only message headers.

In `logging.properties` 2 logfiles are defined, the desired output:

- `request-dumper.log` - headers (`RequestDumperFilter`)
- `custom-dumper.log` - headers and bodies (`FullRequestDumperFilter`)

**The problem:** part of the output gets written into the wrong logfile, the actual output:

- `request-dumper.log` - **headers written twice (`RequestDumperFilter`)**
- `custom-dumper.log` - **only bodies (contents of the `@Override` of `FullRequestDumperFilter`)**

This is probably caused by `FullRequestDumperFilter`, which inherits from `RequestDumperFilter`, which is configured to output into `request-dumper.log` instead of `custom-dumper.log`.

How to get the log filters to output into the right logfiles?

`${CATALINA_HOME}/logging.properties`:

```
handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler, 1request-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 1custom-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

...

1request-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINEST
1request-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1request-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = request-dumper.
1request-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.formatter = org.apache.juli.VerbatimFormatter
org.apache.catalina.filters.RequestDumperFilter.level = FINEST
org.apache.catalina.filters.RequestDumperFilter.handlers = \
  1request-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

1custom-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINEST
1custom-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1custom-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = custom-dumper.
1custom-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.formatter = org.apache.juli.VerbatimFormatter
com.example.FullRequestDumperFilter.level = FINEST
com.example.FullRequestDumperFilter.handlers = \
  1custom-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
```

`FullRequestDumperFilter.java`:

```
package com.example;

import org.apache.catalina.filters.RequestDumperFilter;
import org.apache.commons.io.output.TeeOutputStream;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.juli.logging.Log;
import org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory;

public class FullRequestDumperFilter extends RequestDumperFilter {

    /**
     * The logger for this class.
     */
    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(FullRequestDumperFilter.class);

    /**
     * Log the interesting request parameters, invoke the next Filter in the
     * sequence, and log the interesting response parameters.
     *
     * @param request  The servlet request to be processed
     * @param response The servlet response to be created
     * @param chain    The filter chain being processed
     * @throws IOException      if an input/output error occurs
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet error occurs
     */
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                         FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.doFilter(request, response, chain);

        try {
            HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            BufferedRequestWrapper bufferedReqest = new BufferedRequestWrapper(httpServletRequest);
            BufferedResponseWrapper bufferedResponse = new BufferedResponseWrapper(httpServletResponse);
            doLog("       requestBody\n", bufferedReqest.getRequestBody());
            chain.doFilter(bufferedReqest, bufferedResponse);
            doLog("      responseBody\n", bufferedResponse.getContent());
        } catch (Throwable a) {
            log.error(a);
        }
    }

    private void doLog(String attribute, String value) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(80);
        sb.append(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        sb.append(' ');
        sb.append(attribute);
        sb.append('=');
        sb.append(value);
        log.info(sb.toString());
    }

    private static final class BufferedRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

        private ByteArrayInputStream bais = null;
        private ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
        private BufferedServletInputStream bsis = null;
        private byte[] buffer = null;


        public BufferedRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest req) throws IOException {
            super(req);
            // Read InputStream and store its content in a buffer.
            InputStream is = req.getInputStream();
            this.baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
            int letti;
            while ((letti = is.read(buf)) > 0) {
                this.baos.write(buf, 0, letti);
            }
            this.buffer = this.baos.toByteArray();
        }


        @Override
        public ServletInputStream getInputStream() {
            this.bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(this.buffer);
            this.bsis = new BufferedServletInputStream(this.bais);
            return this.bsis;
        }


        String getRequestBody() throws IOException {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            StringBuilder inputBuffer = new StringBuilder();
            do {
                line = reader.readLine();
                if (null != line) {
                    inputBuffer.append(line.trim());
                }
            } while (line != null);
            reader.close();
            return inputBuffer.toString().trim();
        }

    }


    private static final class BufferedServletInputStream extends ServletInputStream {

        private ByteArrayInputStream bais;

        public BufferedServletInputStream(ByteArrayInputStream bais) {
            this.bais = bais;
        }

        @Override
        public int available() {
            return this.bais.available();
        }

        @Override
        public int read() {
            return this.bais.read();
        }

        @Override
        public int read(byte[] buf, int off, int len) {
            return this.bais.read(buf, off, len);
        }


    }

    public class TeeServletOutputStream extends ServletOutputStream {

        private final TeeOutputStream targetStream;

        public TeeServletOutputStream(OutputStream one, OutputStream two) {
            targetStream = new TeeOutputStream(one, two);
        }

        @Override
        public void write(int arg0) throws IOException {
            this.targetStream.write(arg0);
        }

        public void flush() throws IOException {
            super.flush();
            this.targetStream.flush();
        }

        public void close() throws IOException {
            super.close();
            this.targetStream.close();
        }
    }


    public class BufferedResponseWrapper implements HttpServletResponse {

        HttpServletResponse original;
        TeeServletOutputStream tee;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos;

        public BufferedResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) {
            original = response;
        }

        public String getContent() {
            return bos.toString();
        }

        public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
            return original.getWriter();
        }

        public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
            if (tee == null) {
                bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                tee = new TeeServletOutputStream(original.getOutputStream(), bos);
            }
            return tee;

        }

        @Override
        public String getCharacterEncoding() {
            return original.getCharacterEncoding();
        }

        @Override
        public String getContentType() {
            return original.getContentType();
        }

        @Override
        public void setCharacterEncoding(String charset) {
            original.setCharacterEncoding(charset);
        }

        @Override
        public void setContentLength(int len) {
            original.setContentLength(len);
        }

        @Override
        public void setContentType(String type) {
            original.setContentType(type);
        }

        @Override
        public void setBufferSize(int size) {
            original.setBufferSize(size);
        }

        @Override
        public int getBufferSize() {
            return original.getBufferSize();
        }

        @Override
        public void flushBuffer() throws IOException {
            tee.flush();
        }

        @Override
        public void resetBuffer() {
            original.resetBuffer();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCommitted() {
            return original.isCommitted();
        }

        @Override
        public void reset() {
            original.reset();
        }

        @Override
        public void setLocale(Locale loc) {
            original.setLocale(loc);
        }

        @Override
        public Locale getLocale() {
            return original.getLocale();
        }

        @Override
        public void addCookie(Cookie cookie) {
            original.addCookie(cookie);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean containsHeader(String name) {
            return original.containsHeader(name);
        }

        @Override
        public String encodeURL(String url) {
            return original.encodeURL(url);
        }

        @Override
        public String encodeRedirectURL(String url) {
            return original.encodeRedirectURL(url);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public String encodeUrl(String url) {
            return original.encodeUrl(url);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public String encodeRedirectUrl(String url) {
            return original.encodeRedirectUrl(url);
        }

        @Override
        public void sendError(int sc, String msg) throws IOException {
            original.sendError(sc, msg);
        }

        @Override
        public void sendError(int sc) throws IOException {
            original.sendError(sc);
        }

        @Override
        public void sendRedirect(String location) throws IOException {
            original.sendRedirect(location);
        }

        @Override
        public void setDateHeader(String name, long date) {
            original.setDateHeader(name, date);
        }

        @Override
        public void addDateHeader(String name, long date) {
            original.addDateHeader(name, date);
        }

        @Override
        public void setHeader(String name, String value) {
            original.setHeader(name, value);
        }

        @Override
        public void addHeader(String name, String value) {
            original.addHeader(name, value);
        }

        @Override
        public void setIntHeader(String name, int value) {
            original.setIntHeader(name, value);
        }

        @Override
        public void addIntHeader(String name, int value) {
            original.addIntHeader(name, value);
        }

        @Override
        public void setStatus(int sc) {
            original.setStatus(sc);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void setStatus(int sc, String sm) {
            original.setStatus(sc, sm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getStatus() {
            return original.getStatus();
        }

        @Override
        public String getHeader(String s) {
            return original.getHeader(s);
        }

        @Override
        public Collection<String> getHeaders(String s) {
            return original.getHeaders(s);
        }

        @Override
        public Collection<String> getHeaderNames() {
            return original.getHeaderNames();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried not extending `RequestDumperFilter` and setting up your web project so both filters are invoked on every request?

Comment: That approach is similar to my answer below. By adding the two filters independently into the filter chain both get invoked. Extending an existing filter doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an acceptable solution, I deleted one of the filters in `logging.properties` and set handlers for both filters to `1custom-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler`.

However, the solution still has disadvantages:

- There can be **only one logfile**
- The **handler property has to be configured twice** for technically the same filter
- Ideally there would be log levels (e.g. INFO, FINEST), which would allow different outputs for the custom filter to be stored in different logfiles (with or without body)

`${CATALINA_HOME}/logging.properties`:

```
1custom-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINEST
1custom-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1custom-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = custom-dumper.
1custom-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.formatter = org.apache.juli.VerbatimFormatter
com.example.FullRequestDumperFilter.level = FINEST
com.example.FullRequestDumperFilter.handlers = \
  1custom-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
org.apache.catalina.filters.RequestDumperFilter.level = FINEST
org.apache.catalina.filters.RequestDumperFilter.handlers = \
  1custom-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
```